# firebase realtime database writing data error: values in the firebase are different

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing data to firebase realtime database. When some people register , error occured: values are not what i want . Only my there friends got this error. My registration codes, json format and User.class is below:

```
 {
  country: "Benin",
  heart: 5,
  highscore: "0000000",
  mills: 0,
  password: "12345678",
  points: 0,
  status: false,
  username: "rr"
}
```

Values above is my json format when people register. Geneally i dont get this error. But some people register, my values are changed unexpectedly:

```
{
  a: "Benin",
  b: 5,
  c: "0000000",
  d: mills,
  e: "12345678",
  f: 0,
  g: false,
  h: "rr"
}
```

How can i fix this huge problem?

This is my registration code below(This code works when i click button):

```
                databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                            //finish();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            et_username_layout.setError(getString(R.string.username_already_exists));
                        }else {
                            et_username_layout.setError(null);
                            String id=databaseReference.push().getKey();
                            Users users=new Users(username,password,"0000000",0, country,0,5,false,null);
                            databaseReference.child("users").child(id).setValue(users).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, R.string.registration_is_successful, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        Intent intent_success=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);

                                        et_username_layout.setError("");
                                        et_password_layout.setError("");
                                        et_confirm_password_layout.setError("");
                                        et_username_layout.getEditText().setText("");
                                        et_password_layout.getEditText().setText("");
                                        et_confirm_password_layout.getEditText().setText("");
                                        country_name_tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.select_your_country));
                                        username="";
                                        password="";
                                        confirm_password="";
                                        country="";
                                        //intent_success.setAction(REGISTER_SUCCESSFUL);
                                        //startActivity(intent_success);
                                        //finish();

                                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert_ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                        alert_ad.setCancelable(false);
                                        View view_Ad=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_custum_reg_success,null);
                                        alert_ad.setView(view_Ad);
                                        final AlertDialog dialog=alert_ad.create();
                                        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

                                        Button button=view_Ad.findViewById(R.id.btn_alert_dailog_custom_reg_success);
                                        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }else {
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, R.string.registration_is_not_successful, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
```

and my User.class

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Users {
private String username;
private String password;
private String highscore;
private String country;
private long mills;
private float heart;
private boolean status;

private Friends friends;
private int points;

public Users(String username, String password, String highscore,int points, 
String country,long mills,float heart,boolean status,Friends friends) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.highscore = highscore;
    this.country = country;
    this.mills=mills;
    this.heart=heart;
    this.friends=friends;
    this.status=status;
    this.points=points;
}

public Users() {

}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setPoints(int points) {
    this.points = points;
}

public Friends getFriends() {
    return friends;
}

public void setFriends(Friends friends) {
    this.friends = friends;
}

public float getHeart() {
    return heart;
}

public void setHeart(float heart) {
    this.heart = heart;
}

public long getMills() {
    return mills;
}

public void setMills(long mills) {
    this.mills = mills;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getHighscore() {
    return highscore;
}

public void setHighscore(String highscore) {
    this.highscore = highscore;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}
}
```

Comment: share the code snippets

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to add data to the database. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i added my registration code

Comment: Please also add the content of your `Users` class.

Comment: @AlexMamo i added my user class too

Comment: I cannot see in your code something that can change the name of your properties. Maybe you are also adding data from other parts of your code using different model class.

Comment: @AlexMamo i use only user class in login and registration activity. when i want to change child i use user  id and child field. I dont understand  why i get this error because most of user dont get this error. They registered successfully

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti i shared my code snippets

Comment: Are you updating somewhere in your code user profile? If yes, please add the corresponding code.

Comment: Yes updated but i think previos version do not give this error. i published this app. I wıll send new update and when its updated , i will say my friend to register again. and i will tell you what happened

Comment: Please always responde with @

Comment: @AlexMamo i set minifyEnabled true. does it effect too?

Comment: Setting minifyEnabled true is means that you shrink your code and resources but is not chaning the names of the fields.

Comment: i did minifyEnabled=false .it solved my problem